# Tensorflow: how to obtain the diagonals of multiple matrices (batched mode)

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor which is `[100 X 16 X 16]`. I want to get the diagonal elements of this tensor to get a tensor of shape `[100 X 16]`. I tried the following:

`#sum_cov` is `[100 X 16 X 16]` and `diagonal_elements` is expected to be `[100 X 16]`.

`diagonal_elements = tf.diag_part(sum_cov)`

But, I get the following error:

`Input must have even rank <= 6, input rank is 3 for 'DiagPart'`

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like `tf.matrix_diag_part` does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/diag_part
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_diag_part

[dm0_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469216/tensorflow-how-to-obtain-the-diagonals-of-multiple-matrices-batched-mode#comment68183315_40469216) is right. You want `tf.matrix_diag_part`.

`tf.diag_part` computes the tensor diagonal, where if the input tensor has shape `(D1, ..., Dk, D1, ..., Dk)` then the output tensor has shape `(D1, ..., Dk)` and is such that

```
tf.diag_part(input)[i1, ..., ik] = input[i1, ..., ik, i1, ..., ik]
```

This is why you're getting an error. In order for the above preconditions to hold, the input tensor must have even rank.

`tf.matrix_diag_part`, on the other hand, treats the input tensor as a batch of 2-dimensional matrices, and computes the diagonal of each. So if the input tensor has shape `(I, J, K, ..., M, N)`, the output tensor will have shape `(I, J, K, ..., min(M, N))` and be such that

```
tf.matrix_diag_part(input)[i, j, k, ..., m] = input[i, j, k, ..., m, m]
```

The two functions are identical for rank 2 tensors, but for anything higher than that they're very different beasts.